# Error while accessing the Informatica web service methods

Tags: web-services, informatica-powercenter

I am facing the following error while accessing the Informatica web services methods:

> This represents an internal error at the Informatica PowerCenter Web Services Hub. error code is : WSH_95000

I am able to login and able to get the sessionid provided by the login response. I am passing the same session id for every SOAP call. But able to `initializeDIserverConnection`, unable to do any other calls in DI services.

Please help me if anyone knows the resolution.

Comment: Can anyone recommend some Informatica-specific resources that the OP might use to get his problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

According to Informatica Knowledge Base [article 105634](https://communities.informatica.com/infakb/solution/12/Pages/105634.aspx):

> This error occurs when the Servicename (Integration service name) is not provided under the DIServiceInfo section of Start Workflow operation.